# Who decides what questions to migrate and why?

Tags: feature-request, moderators, migration, topical

We've gotten a couple questions ([What sort of things can cause a whole system to appear to hang for 100s-1000s of milliseconds?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7402/what-sort-of-things-can-cause-a-whole-system-to-appear-to-hang-for-100s-1000s-of) for example, also [Changing Palette for Day/Light Mode using GIMP](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/changing-palette-for-day-light-mode-using-gimp)) that I don't view as inappropriate for the site, but probably still better to target to SO or a different site. Just the presence of the word "game" in a question shouldn't be a reason to migrate here.

Do our moderators have any say about what gets migrated here, or is it entirely up to the moderators of the sending site? Maybe there should be some kind of approval from one moderator on both sides? (But then, I know most SE sites are starved for mod time at the moment also.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the mods on other sites, before they send questions here, at least have somewhat of an understanding of the scope of the site.

For example, the mods on gaming have determined that modding is off topic there, and we've determined it's on topic here, so that agreement is pretty easy.

Those two questions are somewhat random, though.  I won't say they're completely off topic, but the audience the original question was worded for feels a little different.

But there's no approval process for sending a question over, no.

Comment: Just to pop onto this - Gaming's questions can only be migrated to this site by one of the moderators, because there is no explicit migration path available. We'll immediately do map editor and mod questions since this is fairly agreed on both sides, but if anything is questionable, we will try to seek out one of the moderators (typically Noctrine, who I have seen on Chat) just to get a confirmation on the appropriateness.

Answer (score 2):

[Isn't it strange to migrate a question and then immediately close it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73102/isnt-it-strange-to-migrate-a-question-and-then-immediately-close-it)

Not really an *answer*, just another instance of the phenomenon...